# How to add hollows on the surface of mesh and don't make it too complicated for future modelling

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am beginner in Blender, so I need your advice. I want to add some "hollows" on the surface of my mesh to imitate latches and other details. The only way I know how to do this at the moment - enlarge my mesh and extrude the parts I need. But if I go this way, the model will be to complicated for future modelling.[image: base for the robo body]

As you can see - there are a lot of latches, and hollowings on the top of robo body. Which is the best way to imitate them on my mesh?

Comment: What do you mean when you say .... [The model will be too complicated]?   Too complicated for the human modeler, Blender with computer memory resource, some environment?  What is the requirement?

Comment: I mean that model will have a lot of verticles, and, thus too difficult to operate all of them in case of necessity.

Comment: What [thing] that will [operate all of them] concerns you?  The human user or Blender software?  Blender can handle a few X thousand vertices.

Comment: I mean user. The more verticles - the more complicated to change form of an object.

Comment: Try to use your judgement at this stage. All those vertices can cause vertigo at the beginning.  Blender has intricate and advanced tools for manipulating vertices which take time to learn. Archive your files.  Do not be a vertex miser unless you have specific reason.   I would suggest watching Blender tutorial videos at a video website, start with 12, big number.

Comment: Ok, ok. Great thanks for the advice). Try to submerse myself in manuals and video guides)

Comment: I more strongly suggest video tutorial guides for you since you state you are a beginner.  Manuals later.

Answer (score 2):

- Composition.  One might think a sphere/cylinder needs more vertices than a cube. If you place a sphere next to a cube and both are children of an empty then each can have different numbers of vertices mininal to their shape. They might not share any vertices at all.  The location closeness can make them seem as single connected mesh even though they are disconnected.
- Consider searching Blender Parent Empty at some well known video website.
- See videos on Blender armatures if rotation is necessary.
- Single Mesh Example in edit mode.  The sphere vertices have not effect on the cube vertices.

[image]

- The above can be a single mesh.  Yet the composed meshed share no vertices.
- I see textures in your image above.  For low levels of detail you can replace vertices with textures.  All the metal texture and decal paint appearing in your image are probably usefully and sanely done with Blender textures.  You can use a texture to imitate a protusion or indentation especially if that area will not be seen close up.
- Another search here will probably locate more questions on the same topic.